# How to skip NaN values in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

On my dataset, i have a column as below:

```
hist = ['A','FAT',nan,'TAH']
```

**Then i should use a loop to obtain the cells which contains an** `'A'`. Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import math
    from numpy import nan

    for rowId in np.arange(dt.shape[0]):
        for hist in np.arange(10):
            if math.isnan(dt.iloc[rowId,hist])!=True:
                if 'A' in dt.iloc[rowId,hist]:
                    print("A found in: "+str(dt.iloc[rowId,hist]))
```

In the line `if 'A' in dt.iloc[rowId,hist]`
 when the value of `dt.iloc[rowId,hist]` is `NAN` then it complains with, `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

so i decided to add if `math.isnan(dt.iloc[rowId,hist])!=True:`
But, also this one leads to the below error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

***How may i find the values which contains 'A'?***

Comment: "Then i should use a loop " Why do you *need* to use a loop? One of the advantages of using dataframes is that you usually don't need to use loops

Comment: Using loops on a dataframe is definitely not something you want to do. Typical case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about your problem, not why your "solution" is not working.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9081267) a good explanation why we dont want to iterate over our dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over this, you can just use the [**`.str.contains`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) on the column, like:

```
>>> df
     0
0    A
1  FAT
2  NaN
3  TAH
>>> df[0].str.contains('A')
0    True
1    True
2     NaN
3    True
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

You can then for example filter or, obtain the indices:

```
>>> df[df[0].str.contains('A') == True]
     0
0    A
1  FAT
3  TAH
>>> df.index[df[0].str.contains('A') == True]
Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

or we can use `.notna` instead of `== True`:

```
>>> df[df[0].str.contains('A').notna()]
     0
0    A
1  FAT
3  TAH
>>> df.index[df[0].str.contains('A').notna()]
Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

or filter in the `.contains()` like [@Erfan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824401/how-to-skip-nan-values-in-a-loop/56824430?noredirect=1#comment100201435_56824430):

```
>>> df[df[0].str.contains('A', na=False)]
     0
0    A
1  FAT
3  TAH
>>> df.index[df[0].str.contains('A', na=False)]
Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

So you can print the values with:

```
for val in df[df[0].str.contains('A') == True][0]:
    print('A found in {}'.format(val))
```

this gives us:

```
>>> for val in df[df[0].str.contains('A') == True][0]:
...     print('A found in {}'.format(val))
... 
A found in A
A found in FAT
A found in TAH
```

Comment: You can do `df[df[0].str.contains('A')`. Instead of `df[df[0].str.contains('A') == True]`

Comment: Sorry I mean `df[df[0].str.contains('A', na=False)`

Comment: @Erfan: or post filter with `.notna()`.